Is it possible to physically implement lambda calculus
It is quite possible to build models of the turning machine that work (of cause you have to ignore the requirement for unlimited tape).  What I am curious is is it possible to implement a model of lambda calculus more or less directly.
Just to head off the trivial answer building a Turing machine (or any other computer) that emulates lambda calculus isn't what I'm looking for.

Like this? https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/319838.319864

what do you mean in implement? building hardware? otherwise if you consider imperative languages like C++ or C, they are turing-complete and they are based on state-like idea of Turing machines, while functional languages like ML are based on the lambda calculus.

I'm not exactly sure exactly what you have in mind when you say "implement a model of lambda calculus more or less directly" and without "building a Turing machine or any other computer that emulates lambda calculus"
Would you be interested in creating your own lamda-calculus-inspired computer architecture? If yes, I'd begin by creating a way to encode lambda calculus expressions in binary.
